# Eclipse Mars doesn't start

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-mars

I installed the Eclipse Mars and some plugins.
When I try to open a new workspace (like the Figure 1) the eclipse stop and doesnt start. If I used another created workspace in my computer sometimes it works.

[image]

The Eclipse stop in this phase of initialization:

[image]

With the message:
Loading org.eclipse.emf.edit

Comment: try to increase xms param in eclipse.ini

Comment: Is there anything in the workspace log (<ws_dir>/.metadata/.log)?